# Array used in initial values only works when fully defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I basically want to do the following:

```js
const intialDefaultValues = {
  weekdays: {
    monday: [
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" }
    ],
    tuesday: [
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" }
    ],
    wednesday: [
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
      { startTime: "", endTime: "" }
    ],
// ...
```

As you can see it becomes pretty repetitive and I would like to re-use a part of the code:

```js
const daySchema = [
  { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
  { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
  { startTime: "", endTime: "" }
];

const intialDefaultValues = {
  weekdays: {
    monday: daySchema,
    tuesday: daySchema,
    wednesday: daySchema,
// etc.
```

But this does not work...

## Attempts

One [source](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c) I've found mentioned *passing by reference* for Objects and Arrays in Javascript. So this made my try several methods to clone it. Still no luck.

I've tried the good ol' `myArray.slice()` method, as the ES6 way: `[...myArray]`:

```js
const intialDefaultValues = {
  weekdays: {
    monday: [...daySchema],
    tuesday: [...daySchema],
    wednesday: [...daySchema], 
  // etc.
```

## Reproducable example

I've created a CodeSandbox to display the issue I'm facing: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-wave-e7gty

#### Verbose version

To see this error happen do as follows:

1. In the first form, click on the word Wednesday. It should pop open.
2. Then click on submit

**Outcome:** the name and first "From" and "To" fields should be red. This works!

#### Compact version

Now for the compact example:

1. In the second form, click on the word Wednesday. It should pop open.
2. Then click on submit

**Expected Outcome:** the name and first "From" and "To" fields should be red.

**Actual Outcome:** only the name is validating

Comment: What does not work for the initialDefaultValuesCompact, it works fine for me.

Comment: You can create a function that returns the new values instead of referencing the same defaults in three places. `function getDefaultDaySchema(){return [
  { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
  { startTime: "", endTime: "" },
  { startTime: "", endTime: "" }
]}` And use it like `intialDefaultValues =  `
  weekdays: {
    monday: getDefaultDaySchema(),
    tuesday: getDefaultDaySchema()...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a function for getting an object with empty value and another to get a day.

```js
const
    getRange = (startTime = "", endTime = "") => ({ startTime, endTime }),
    getDay = (length, fn, ...params) => Array.from({ length }, _ => fn(...params));

console.log(getDay(3, getRange));
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works. So what is happening here, is it a 'value by reference' sort of thing? Or is the assignment different when using a/that function?

Comment: you get a fresh object from `getRange` for each call and `getDay` returs an amount of independent objects.

Comment: Oké. Wasn't the 'new array method' also returning a fresh array each time? Or was it then that somehow the object inside was still a reference to the same object?

Comment: it's always a new object.